# Which entity actually scans the .user.ini files i.e. .htaccess files in case of HTTP Apache web server?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, configuration-files, apache-config

I'm using a laptop that runs on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit** Operating System

I've installed the latest version of **XAMPP** pre-configured installer on this laptop.

This has installed **PHP 7.2.12** and **Apache/2.4.37 (Win32)** on my laptop.

I come across below note from the [PHP Manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php#11configuration.file.per-user)  :

> **.user.ini files**
>
> In addition to the main php.ini file, PHP scans for INI files in each
>   directory, starting with the directory of the requested PHP file, and
>   working its way up to the current document root (as set in
>   `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`). In case the PHP file is outside the
>   document root, only its directory is scanned.

From the above text it's clear that **.htaccess files** are exclusivey used when running PHP as Apache module. In no other implementation of PHP **.htaccess files** can be used.

Tell me my above perception is right or wrong?

After reading the above text from PHP Manual one doubt has created in my mind.

My doubt is which entity actually scans the .user.ini files i.e. .htaccess files in case of HTTP Apache web server as **.htaccess files** can only be used exclusivey with Apache module implementation of PHP?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Why should the server process these ini files - this should be up to PHP. Additionally, there is a difference between these ini files and a `htaccess` file

Comment: Your assumption about dynamic configuration files ("`.htaccess`") is correct, since that has nothing to do with php, it is a feature of the apache http server. The mentioned "`.user.ini`" files are a feature of the php core engine. You need to understand the difference between the two components.

Answer (score 0):

[.htacess files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) are a means to configure Apache HTTPD on a per-directory basis.

There are some configuration options which are specific to the PHP Apache module which you can put there.

There are some configuration options which can affect requests involving PHP in general. e.g. a mod_rewrite directive would modify a request no matter if it ultimately was handled by mod_php, PHP via a FastCGI implementation, or not involve PHP at all.